# Particle moving on circular path, is work being done?

Tags: kinematics, work

If a particle moves along a circular path, there is no work being done on it. Is it true or false?

Comment: Work is done *on* the particle if the particle's kinetic energy is increasing.  Is it?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

Work is something that a force does on a body by changing its velocity in absolute value. Remember that work is the amount of energy that you give or take to or from a system. The energy of a single particle depends on velocity, so work has to change the absolute value of velocity.

In a circular, uniform motion we have a velocity that's always changing, and that's why we need a centripetal force to have a circular motion (and a physical reason to have a force, like an attached string, gravitational or electrostatic interaction etc), a force that always changes the direction of the velocity. For circular uniform motion, the force is always orthogonal to the velocity: as the work done on the system after a certain interval of time $\Delta t$ is the integral of $\vec F\cdot\vec v$ over that interval, this kind of force cannot change the absolute value of the velocity, as the dot product and the integral are always zero (remember, $\vec F$ points to the center, $\vec v$ points in a direction that is tangential to the circle). So, in standard uniform circular motion, you have a force, but it doesn't do work.

But uniform circular motion is not the only motion that you can do on a circular path. You can always add a tangential force (and a physical reason to have it, like a drag or someone pushing). If the particle is bound to move on the circle, the motion will remain circular, but the total force will have a tangential component. Thus work will be done, and the energy (and the absolute value of the velocity) will change.

So, in general, there exist circular motions on which work is done by the forces. But the answer ultimately depends on forces, and the physical reason for them to exist.